# How to pass parameters to ocl kernel using c++ opencl api?

Tags: c++, opencl

how to pass parameters being treated in the .cl file as a preprocessor define using c++ ocl bindings?

Meaning:

**foo.cl**

```
# define LIMIT 12
typedef struct {
    uint i[LIMIT];
} foomatic;
```

turns to

**foo_nodefs.cl**

```
typedef struct {
    uint i[LIMIT]; // main.cpp passing LIMIT to set it
} foomatic;
```

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

Use cl::Program::build with the option "-D LIMIT=12".

Comment: What OS and GPU are you using?

Comment: I use Windows 7 and 8 on AMD and Nvidia GPUs, but that should not matter as I am working from the OpenCL 1.1 C++ bindings spec.